# WSO2 Governance Registry with CA API Gateway

Tags: web-services, wsdl, wso2

I am currently performing proof-of-concept on WSO2 Governance Registry with two middle-ware products, CA API Gateway and Software AG webMethods. I have installed WSO2 Governance Registry in my local machine running on Windows 10 and successfully ran through the Quick Guide provided by WSO2.

I have following questions:

1. I managed to connect to the local WSO2 Governance Registry from CA API Gateway which is installed in a local virtual machine. I successfully published one SOAP service to WSO2 Governance Registry, but the service is not searchable in both WSO2 Publisher and WSO2 Store. What settings need to be configured for the published service to be visible in both publisher and store?
2. In the management console, I can see the published service under the Metadata tab, in the Endpoints section. Kindly advise why the published service is not listed under the SOAP services or WSDL section?

Please advise.

Thanks.

Rgds,
neo

Answer (score 0):

If you can explain which API(governance Java API, Governance REST API, etc) you have used to publish this SOAP Service, we can help you to overcome this issue.

Based on the provided details, it seems you are publishing a SOAP service as Endpoint. To avoid this issue you have to correctly set the media type of the artifact( example if you are using [governance rest API](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance540/Governance+REST+API#GovernanceRESTAPI-Createanewasset), URL should be https://localhost:9443/governance/restservices).

Comment: I am connecting to WSO2 using UDDI Standard APIs (http://localhost:9763/juddiv3/services/inquiry, http://localhost:9763/juddiv3/services/security, http://localhost:9763/juddiv3/services/publish). How do I publish my SOAP services to fall under the SOAP service category in the management console? Besides that, how do I make the published SOAP services available for search in both WSO2 store and WSO2 publisher?

Comment: I managed to make the SOAP service visible on WSO2 store and publisher after changing the media type to application/vnd.wso2-soap-service+xml in the management console (Home->Resources->Browse). However my question is how to include the media type during publishing the SOAP service to WSO2 from middleware.